# laravel routes "/" Forbidden

Tags: laravel, permissions, routes, server

i make my website with laravel.
This is my routes.php:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'),function(){
Route::get('/', 'PostController');
});
Route::get('login','HomeController@dologin');
Route::post('login','HomeController@dologin');
Route::get('logout','HomeController@dologout');

Route::get('registration', 'HomeController@registration');
Route::post('registration', 'HomeController@registration');

Route::post('uploading', array('uses'=>'HomeController@uploading','as'=>'home.uploading'));

Route::resource('post','PostController');
Route::resource('comment','CommentController',array('except'=>array('store')));
Route::post('comment/{id}', array('uses'=>'CommentController@store','as'=>'comment.store'));
Route::resource('user','UserController');
Route::get('user/{id}/description_edit', array('uses'=>'UserController@description_edit','as'=>'user.description_edit'));
Route::put('user/{id}/description_update', array('uses'=>'UserController@description_update','as'=>'user.description_update'));
Route::get('user/{id}/password_edit', array('uses'=>'UserController@password_edit','as'=>'user.password_edit'));
Route::put('user/{id}/password_update', array('uses'=>'UserController@password_update','as'=>'user.password_update'));
```

if i access localhost/au/public it will automatically redirect to localhost/au/public/login (it did works on my local server)

But after i uploaded it to web host server,
When i accessed rivelapark.com/au/public it doesn't automatically redirect me to rivelapark.com/au/public/login. i got forbidden message.

Is There Anyone Could Help me so when i accessed rivelapark.com/au/public it automatically redirect me to rivelapark.com/au/public/login ? Thank You Guys.

Answer (score 0):

There are two probable causes:

1. You need to enable apache rewrite on the server (usually with
   a2enmod rewrite)
2. Allow set AllowOverride All instead of
   AllowOverride None for that webhost.

Also, you should set your web root to be "public" so that your php files are not outside of the document root.

Comment: how to do it? steps please

Comment: Which type of server is it? (dedicated, VPS)?  Which operating system? Which distribution (if linux)? Do you have admin or root level access?